# Waiting a random amount of time to play a sound in Android

Tags: java, android, random, android-mediaplayer

In an application I am working on I need to allow the user to click a button that will play a sound from res/raw using MediaPlayer. That part is going well and works fine, however I would like to make it wait a random amount of time after the user hits the button before playing the sound. 
Does anyone know of the correct way to implement this or have any ideas of which direction I should be looking?

Comment: [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use Thread.sleep() (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(Random amount of time);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Get randomness with java.util.random (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

EDIT: Actually, this might not be a good idea if you dont want the User Interface to get frozen while waiting for the sound to play.

Comment: First off thank you, I figured that's where I should be looking. In response to your edit: if I run the mediaplayer in a separate thread and then follow your advice it will allow it to run without freezing the UI, correct?

Comment: Yes, if it's running in a separate thread it will not freeze the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try also using previous post:

```
private long generateLongRandom(long min, long max) {
    return random.nextLong((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```